# Are rake tasks suitable for long running processes in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm planing in using a rake task to develop a long running background process for my rails application. Are rake tasks appropriate for this kind of processes? Ideally, I would like wrap it inside a linux daemon to be able to start and end the process easily.

If it's not the best option, which are the alternatives? I'm trying to avoid using a cron-based solution to avoid having to worry about the schedule and the posibility of having diferent running instances of the same process overlapping between them.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your needs, but cron-like jobs are often handled by a gem called god: http://godrb.com/

Comment: What kind of job it will handle?

Comment: @retro it will be updating a summary table, retrieving new & updated records to recalculate averages, total & sums.

Comment: It really depends how long-running and your server resources. The biggest issue with such an approach is that your whole Rails app will be loaded into memory for and during the rake task. That could be 100/200+ mb ram for the duration. How long is the task likely to run?

Comment: @DamienRoche, I don't know yet. It will depend of the volume of data to process. My idea is to have something like a windows service that is running non stop, with a sleep between executions (like 30s or 1min). I don't mind how much memory it consumes, as I want to use rails as much as posible: active record, validations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with this [extension](https://gist.github.com/kares/1024726#file-scheduled_job-rb).

```
class MyJob

  include Delayed::ScheduledJob

  run_every 1.day

  def display_name
    "MyJob"
  end

  def perform
    # code to run ...
  end
end
```

Or manually enqueue another job with `Time.now + 5.minutes` for example after current job is finished inside perform method.

Comment: Nice! I never would have thought of this solution! Clever and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the delayed_job gem?

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

From their documentation:

Delayed::Job (or DJ) encapsulates the common pattern of asynchronously executing longer tasks in the background.

It is a direct extraction from Shopify where the job table is responsible for a multitude of core tasks. Amongst those tasks are:

- sending massive newsletters
- image resizing
- http downloads
- updating smart collections
- updating solr, our search server, after product changes
- batch imports
- spam checks

Comment: I'd advise sidekiq over delayed_job. It uses threads, uses less resources, and has been more stable in my experience.

Comment: Yes I have, what worries me with delayed job, etc. is something I have not clear with the documentation available. What will happen if my job is scheduled every 5 minutes, but it takes 10 minutes to execute? Thats why im aiming to a "windows service" approach

Comment: thanks, I will have to keep it in mind the next time I use delayed_job :)

Answer (score 0):

it might depend on the kind of background jobs you need to run.

Basically if you need some sort of post processing on data the users enter, like rendering images for posts, do some async integration with third party resources, etc. then you better off with using Sidekiq (yeah, it's better than DelayedJob as people suggested)

But if you need to run something on schedule, like some say night downloads, cleaning up blocked users and stuff, then writing a rake task and kick it in with a cron task might be a perfectly useful option, coz you could use those tasks from CLI whenever you need to run them on demand